# Classes with same name

Tags: java, api, import, package

I created a class called Rectangle and placed it into a package that I called 'shapes'. I then created another class called Test, from which I imported both my custom Rectangle class and the java.awt.Rectangle class. Test referred to a Rectangle class. When I tried to compile, I got the message "reference to Rectangle is ambiguous".

However, I then placed my own Rectangle class in the default package (i.e. no package names declared), and imported the java.awt.Rectangle class as before. At compile time, the compiler used the Rectangle class that was in the default package, not the one that I had imported from the java.awt package.

Any clarification on when there is or is not a clash, and if there isn't, which class the compiler uses, when both file names are the same, would be appreciated.

Here is the code, as requested:

Test class

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
        System.out.println(r.width);
    }
}
```

Custom Rectangle class

```
public class Rectangle {

    public int width = 1;

}
```

Comment: It would really help if you'd show a short but complete example of the code in each case. My guess is that you were using wildcard imports...

Comment: "However, I then placed my own Rectangle class in the default package (i.e. no package names declared), and imported the java.awt.Rectangle class as before. At compile time, the compiler used the Rectangle class that was in the default package, not the one that I had imported from the java.awt package." I have now tested this using import java.awt.Rectangle and now it's the java.awt.Rectangle class that is used, not the one in the default package...

Comment: Yup, but you didn't say *how* you'd imported the class. Now that you've provided the code, it's clearer - it's because you've got `import java.awt.*`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the wildcard import issue, but why does going from using import java.awt.*; to import java.awt.Rectangle; cause the compiler to use the java.awt.Rectangle class instead of the custom Rectangle class that's in the default package?

Comment: Because you've basically said "When I say Rectangle, I mean exactly java.awt.Rectangle." I would suggest avoiding the default package though, at which point that aspect is irrelevant, and you just need to consider conflicts between classes in different packages.

Comment: You probably want to read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5 though...

Comment: Thanks for the tips and link. Is the following therefore correct: If a class is referenced from a program, and there are multiple classes with this name, the priority is as follows 1. Use imported class if its full path is specified in the import statement 2. Use the class in the same default package as the referencing class 3. Use the class that has been imported by use of a wildcard import. ? If so, is this written anywhere in the Java specification?

Comment: That sounds about right - and the part of the spec I linked to should give those rules, although it may be tricky to find.

Answer (score 1):

Since java 5, you do not need to import classes from default package any longer - which means java does always import all your default classes by "default". This is why it is named like this.

So, what ever you put into a default package, it is imported in all your classes. This may lead to big classes during runtime and unnecessary memory load. It is not wise to put classes into the default package without a very specific reason.

Beside the default package, java also always imports classes from System, String, Integer, Array, Float from the java.lang package. You never had to import these classes, didnt you?
Classes in the default package behave the same.

To your solution now, if you want to access the class with the same name, but not within the default package you can always use the full qualified name like package.Class

```
my.package.MyClass c = new my.package.MyClass();
c.doSomething();

MyClass defaultClass = new MyClass();
defaultClass.doSomethingWithinAClassFromDefaultPackage();
```

Comment: *"java also always imports classes from System, String, Integer, Array, Float,etc."*, you mean classes of the package [*java.lang*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html).

Comment: yes, exactly. These are not within the default package, the intention was to show that java imports other classes automatically without notice. I'll update the answer to point this out more.

Comment: Btw your answer currently misses the following part: *"However, I then placed my own Rectangle class in the default package (i.e. no package names declared), and imported the java.awt.Rectangle class as before. At compile time, the compiler used the Rectangle class that was in the default package, not the one that I had imported from the java.awt package."*. I think Jon is right here, that OP uses wildcard imports. If not, then he would need the qualified class name (like in your example).

Comment: "This may lead to big classes during runtime and unnecessary memory load" - I think you've misunderstood what imports do.

Comment: This depends on the JVM you're using. On very old java ME on Blackberry Phones, it copied over some of the classes and the class file got bigger. This was never an issue on SE ony any platform, as far as I'm aware of.

Comment: Well in Java *language* terms, imports only affect what names mean. It sounds like the Blackberry platform was doing some very odd things - if you're going to base any part of your answer on that, I would be very explicit about it. It's also unclear what you mean by " java also always imports classes from System, String, Integer, Array, Float from the java.lang package" - that makes it sound like System is a package too, etc. It's just that the compiler imports *everything* from the java.lang package by default...

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  It also has some factual errors, as Jon has pointed out.

Comment: so David I'm interested in your answer then so I can learn from you. Thanks.